# Print a javascript variable in php

Tags: javascript, php

I am selecting a payment method and making an AJAX call But I am not able to print the `paymentOption` parameter

I tried storing it in a cookie

```
if(paymentOption == "default_cod"){
            processOrderWithCOD();
            optionPayment = Cash;
        }
document.cookie = "$payment_option = $this.optionPayment";
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
                $paymentOptionDisplay =  $_COOKIE['payment_option'];
                echo $paymentOptionDisplay ?>
```

I am just trying to print paymentOption but later on its value is changed so need to save it and print

Comment: any changes in the client that need to be sent to the server need to be sent to the server by the client

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that if JS and PHP live in the same document, the PHP will be executed first (at the server) and the JS will be executed second (at the browser)--and the two will NEVER interact (excepting where you output JS with PHP, which is not really an interaction between the two engines).

In other words, if the two live in the same document and no extra interaction with the server is performed, JS can NOT cause any effect in PHP. Furthermore, PHP is limited in its effect on JS to the simple ability to output some JS or something in context of JS.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concept.. Can you suggest a solution for this problem?
Can't I store it in a cookie and then display the variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
$paymentOptionDisplay =  $_COOKIE['payment_option'];
```

Cookies usually will not be available until the page is reloaded / refreshed, which is why you're not getting the value that you're expecting. You'd really have to do the payment calculation in PHP and store it in a $_SESSION if you're looking for it to persist like a cookie.